# How to Implement GPUImageMaskFilter using GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

I need to Cut from the Full Image using the mask and created the masked Image.

[image: Full Image] **+**[image: Mask Image]**=**[image]

I tried the following:

```
UIImage *imgMask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mask.png"];
UIImage *imgBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Full.png"];



GPUImageMaskFilter *maskingFilter = [[GPUImageMaskFilter alloc] init];


GPUImagePicture * maskGpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imgMask ];

GPUImagePicture *FullGpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imgBgImage ];




[maskGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[maskGpuImage processImage];


[maskingFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];


[FullGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[FullGpuImage processImage];



UIImage *OutputImage = [maskingFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

But , my generated output image is: [image]

Please guys join hands.
Cheers.

Also,Thanks to [BradLarson](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Comment: Good question. I have the similar task and right now trying to solve it with two images - one for mask and one for bound.

Comment: That's a really alarming output image.

Comment: As a first step, try swapping the texture indices like this: `[FullGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter atIndex:0];` `[maskGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter atIndex:1];` See if that gets you any closer to your desired output.

Answer (score 5):

The mask is the **second** target, as can been seen in the filter shader code (textureColor2).

```
//Averages mask's the RGB values, and scales that value by the mask's alpha
//
//The dot product should take fewer cycles than doing an average normally
//
//Typical/ideal case, R,G, and B will be the same, and Alpha will be 1.0

 lowp float newAlpha = dot(textureColor2.rgb, vec3(.33333334, .33333334, .33333334)) * textureColor2.a;

 gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.xyz, newAlpha);
```

Then you need to "invert" your mask : white heart on black background, as the filter uses the "weight" of the RGB pixel value to set the alpha value on the target image.

So your code should be

```
// Image first, Mask next
[FullGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[FullGpuImage processImage];

[maskingFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

[maskGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[maskGpuImage processImage];
```

and your mask (ok I did an ugly quick test, use a proper image) like

[image: white heart on black background]

for the expected result.

[image: masked image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a mask filter but an alpha mask blend.

I implemented one [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/03623e2506cfaee144df24a6aa8151beadb05093/Source/Filters/NBUGPUImageFilterProvider.m#L43) like this:

```
// GPUImage shader strings
NSString * const kNBUAlphaMaskShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

 void main()
 {
     lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
     lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

     gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.xyz, textureColor2.a);
 }
 );
```

Simply keeps the colors from one image and the alpha channel of the second one.

Then [create](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/03623e2506cfaee144df24a6aa8151beadb05093/Source/Filters/NBUGPUImageFilterProvider.m#L331) a `GPUImageTwoInputFilter`:

```
GPUImageTwoInputFilter * alphaMask = [[GPUImageTwoInputFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromString:kNBUAlphaMaskShaderString];
```

I'm not sure if a similar blend filter has been added to GPUImage since.

---

Just checked again to see if there's a built-in blend that does it, and there isn't. But the blend filter I used as inspiration is still there ([GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/2f8e61c4ffcdfa93ee3d8f39f8110e61cfc3daf1/framework/Source/GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter.h)). It merges two images using the alpha mask to mix them. The filter mentioned above doesn't require a second "empty" image.

Comment: Thx. Also, let me try this one too .